# How to constrain Python launcher for Windows?

Tags: python, launcher

The "new" Python launcher for Windows can somehow find which Python versions you have installed on your computer and run the appropriate one according to what you specify. I need the launcher to not find the Python version I have installed with Anaconda (3.7.3). Is that possible?

I need this so that the default Python run with `py -3` is another one (3.6) but I do not want to remove Anaconda.

Also, `py` is finding the Anaconda python version on my machine but not finding the one installed with cygwin (2.7), so this seems possible. On an aside, any idea why this might happen? And I guess how to replicate it?